# VBA crashes when instantiating 'Match' object

Tags: vba

I am puzzled why does following code crashes on line with "'<-----".
That being said I get no error message and VBE is set to break on all errors, not just unhandled, nor did I have then time to write the error handing procedures yet.

There is also the fact that this is a procedure from a larger class module and when code hits a break and I try to expand in Locals window `Me` entire application(Excel) crashes.

All other methods in this class module work fine, and all variables that are relevant to the problematic procedure are listed bellow.
Relevant Variables:

```
VectorPatterns(1) = "\d+\sramp\s\d+\s"
PatternList( 1 To 1) = ( "\d+\sramp\s\d+\s" )
Text = "5 ramp 12 "
Ahead = 0
```

The Problematic Code

```
Private Function ReadNext(ByRef Text As String, Optional Ahead As Integer = 0) As FoundPattern
    Dim FoundItems As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Dim FoundItem As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    Dim APattern As Integer
    Dim FoundPattern As FoundPattern
    Dim PatternLookbehind As String
    Dim DemitedPatternList As String


    DemitedPatternList = Join(PatternList, "|")

    If Ahead > 0 Then
        PatternLookbehind = _
            "^(?<=" & _
            DemitedPatternList & _
            "){" & Ahead & "}"
    Else
        PatternLookbehind = "^"
    End If

    For APattern = 1 To PatternCount
        Regex.Pattern = PatternLookbehind & VectorPatterns(APattern).Regex
        Set FoundItems = Regex.Execute(Text)
        If FoundItems.Count > 0 Then
            Set FoundItem = FoundItems.Item(1)                '<-----
            FoundPattern.Type = VectorPatterns(APattern).Type
            FoundPattern.Value = FoundItem.Value
        End If
    Next APattern

    ReadNext = FoundPattern
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FoundItems.Item(i)` is zero-based. This means the first item is `i = 0`, second is `i = 1` etc.

The problem in your code comes when `FoundItems.Count = 1`. You will have to use `Set FoundItem = FoundItems.Item(0)` to return the first item.

More in [this tutorial](http://www.herongyang.com/VBScript/RegExp-MatchCollection-and-SubMatches-Collection-Object.html).